# paginate json API Laravel 5 Call to a member function links() on array

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

Trying to get data from an API and still use the Paginate but it does not work.

I get this error:
Call to a member function links() on array

This is my API controller that where i get the data from:

```
$positions = DB::table('position')
->join('company', 'position.company_id', '=', 'company.id')
->select('position.*', 'company.name')
->paginate(5);

   if (!$positions) {
    return response()->json(['message' =>'There is no positions', 'code' =>404], 404);
} else {
       //echo "hit bby first";
   return response()->json(['data' => $positions], 200);
}
```

This is the controller which gets data from the API through JSON:

```
$jsonurl = "http://localhost/laravel.dev/index.php/positions";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
$newarray = json_decode(json_encode($json_output), True);

 $data = array(
    'positions' => $newarray['data'],
);

return view('mypage', $data);
```

This is in my view mypage where i loop through the code

```
@foreach($positions['data'] as $position)

    {{$position['title']}}
    {{$position['location']}}

@endforeach
{{positions->links()}}
```

And this is what the array looks like when i try to echo it in the view:

```
Array
(
    [total] => 14
    [per_page] => 5
    [current_page] => 1
    [last_page] => 3
    [next_page_url] => http://localhost/laravel.dev/index.php/positions?page=2
    [prev_page_url] => 
    [from] => 1
    [to] => 5
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [company_id] => 1
                    [title] => Software Developer
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [company_id] => 2
                    [title] => Accountant

                )
```

Comment: Please define "does not work". What is the error?

Comment: @Jaw.sh Illegal string offset 'title'

Comment: That means that `{{$position['title']}}` is accessing an invalid key. What happens if you replace `{{$position['title']}}` with `{{ dd($position) }}`? Does the array structure look like you'd expect?

Comment: That means you're `$positions` equals the pagination array, not the `data` key. `14` is `total`.

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg should your `foreach` go over `$positions['data']` instead of just `$positions`?

Comment: @JeffLambert, he passes `$positions` as `$newarray['data']` but that's not what's going on. Either I'm missing something or he is.

Comment: @JeffLambert correct but now i get Call to a member function links() on array instead :)

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg Where is the links method coming from? Shouldn't `$positions` just be a `json_decoded` array? Also, why are you decoding, then encoding it again just to decode it? From the outside, that doesn't make much sense

Comment: @JeffLambert if i dont i get Trying to get property of non-object  as an error

Comment: I also have gotten the same problem. Getting error like, "Call to a member function links() on array". I can't use the collection, need to use an array. What's the solution please?